mdadm in script produces nonsesnsical error when muting output to /dev/null
Some really weird Voodoo magic is going on with mdadm in my script:
Creating RAID with: mdadm --create --run --level=1 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md/4  /dev/nvme1n1p4  /dev/nvme0n1p4
mdadm: /dev/nvme1n1p4 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
       size=495889752K  mtime=Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1p4 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Sun Jul 21 16:58:43 2024
mdadm: array /dev/md/4 started.
------------
Creating RAID with: mdadm --create --run --level=1 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md/4  /dev/nvme1n1p4  /dev/nvme0n1p4  > /dev/null
mdadm: You have listed more devices (4) than are in the array(2)!
------------
Creating RAID with: mdadm --create --run --level=1 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md/4  /dev/nvme1n1p4  /dev/nvme0n1p4  > /dev/null 2>&1
mdadm: You have listed more devices (5) than are in the array(2)!

Just look at the 2 lower examples where I try to mute the output of mdadm to only produce the output I want. It produces a completely unrelated error message.
Here is the bash section that causes the issue:
else \
  echo "Continuing with Software RAID1"; \
  for partition in {1..4}; do \
    raidCommand="mdadm --create --run --level=1 --metadata=1.2 --raid-devices=${targetDriveCount} /dev/md/${partition} " && \
    for drive in $targetDrives; do \
      if [[ "$drive" == *nvme* ]]; then \
        raidCommand="${raidCommand} ${drive}p${partition} "; \
      else \
        raidCommand="${raidCommand} ${drive}${partition} "; \
      fi; \
    done; \
    raidCommand="${raidCommand} > /dev/null 2>&1" && \
    echo "Creating RAID with: ${raidCommand}" && \
    $raidCommand; \
  done; \
fi && \

The script works, but this output is not clean at all. How can I prevent this from happening?
And yeah I know, the script does not look great, but it should do for now. And yes, it actually is a single liner intentionally. But that does not explain the error in any way I can understand at all. What is going on?

AFAIK the unquoted expansion $raidCommand performs word splitting and globbing, but doesn't magically perform redirections - so > ,  /dev/null, and 2>&1 are all passed to mdadm as additional arguments

... see for example Passing a command with arguments and redirection to a function or How to use output redirection dynamically?

What's with all the trailing \  characters?

@steeldriver. Well this seems to make sense. A to actually. Because the 2>&1 is counted extra again. BUT: The redirect is done in some way. It actually mutes all output of mdadm - except the error you see in this example. Really strange why it is a mix of both.
ChrisDavies The \ is required, as this script is a single line script. It can be copy&pasted to bash directly without requiring a separate .sh file for example. It is just formatted for readability, but the formatting has no actual meaning. It is just a very long continuos line.

"It actually mutes all output of mdadm - except the error you see in this example" – I think the tool reports the fatal error and does nothing more; so "all the output except" is not muted, it's not there in the first place.

Side note: there are better (or at least less cumbersome) ways to be able to "copy&paste to bash directly": bracketed paste, grouping commands ({ … }), edit-and-execute-command (Ctrl+x, Ctrl+e) or even putting everything in a shell function and calling it.

@KamilMaciorowski That is not correct. The RAID indeed is created and is created correctly as verified with mdadm --detail. It is, as the script also stops all raids and deletes the superblocks and wipes all drives with wipefs -fa before creating new RAIDs. So it cannot be a still existing RAID. With that said, it works if I "eval $raidCommand" It is just a wrong interpretation, as it mixes things in a nonsensical way. It takes the redirection as input, but also mutes all but 1 message. Without it the stdout is looooooong.
